# How does torque not increase velocity in a constant power engine/mechanism?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, torque, rotation

I know the formula of Power(P)=T(torque)*velocity(v)

thus for constant power output, there is an inverse relationship between torque and angular velocity. But on an intuitive level, and without performing experiments, isn't my logic correct that- on increasing torque, the turning effect of that force speeds up and strengthens, so the velocity should also increase. But velocity starts to decrease as if there was a computer program already told to do so if torque levels rise. How and why does this actually happen?

Comment: What *physical situation* are you imagining here where power is held constant? How do you expect us to explain what's decreasing the velocity without saying what's holding the power constant?

Comment: like in cars-refer to Steeven's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you increase the torque, then the angular velocity will - depending on what else is involved - increase more according according to Newton's 2nd law (in its rotational version):

$$\sum \tau=I\alpha.$$

This will thus also increase the power.

If you want the power to remain constant, then you are correct that the speed must decrease. It won't due so by itself. You have to apply some mechanism to keep the speed down or to make it decrease. Maybe you do that by exerting another, counteracting torque. This depends on the scenario.

Remember, that just because there is a mathematical relationship between some properties, we still have to physically interpret what is actually taking place in real life. In your scenario, you seem to assume the power to be able to stay constant while you increase the torque, and that naturally leads to your reasonable confusion of how the speed could ever decrease by itself. You are perfectly right that this would not happen - the reason is that your assumption of constant power in a natural state might be wrong. Keeping power constant require some interference with the system as explained.

Comment: hey, Steveeven again!
so it means that there is indeed a program designed in cars for constant power output to control the power output, and without that the velocity would indeed just increase?

Comment: and just because we observe that there is an inverse relationship between distance from the pivot point and the force applied for constant torque, we develop and make sense of this torque formula
2) So torque is really the turning effect of force acting at a distance from the pivot point, and also acts as a force having produced changes in angular momentum (rotational counterpart of linear momentum), so is rotationally equivalent to force, and is the result of the force too(by turning effect being torque and cause being force)?

Comment: @Aveer Is a car designed for constant power output in spite of increased torque generated? That sounds odd - why would we ever want to apply a larger torque from the engine without a greater output? What type of power output are we talking about here?

Comment: @Aveer I'm sorry, I do not understand your second comment. Would you mind rephrasing?

Comment: Steeven, I said that:
Is it because of our observation of the direct relationship of torque and distance from center, that we can make sense of this formula (I know about the derivation through angular momentum)?
And torque is the result of the application of a force on a rigid body pivoted at some point (thus it is the turning effect, with the application of force from us being the cause) but is also analogous to a force because it changes the angular momentum of the body (which is a characteristic of a force).

Comment: @Aveer A force does not change the angular momentum. A force *and the distance* changes the angular momentum. Force-and-distance is covered by torque, so you can say that a torque changes the angular momentum.

Comment: @Aveer "*Is it because of our observation of the direct relationship of torque and distance from center, that we can make sense of this formula*" I am still not sure of what your question is exactly. What formula are you referring to? What do you mean by "make sense" of a formula?

Comment: Well- I meant that T=F r sin(theta), where r is the distance    and f=dp/dt where p is the linear momentum, and if torque=dL/dt where L is angular momentum, so torque is a rotational equivalent, and the distance part just tells us the effect of the force at various distances expressed as a single entitiy called torque.  IS THAT WHAT ALL OF YOU MEAN?

Comment: @Aveer Your described formulas are correct. So, I will say: yes, that is what we mean.

Comment: thank you very much